# A "simple math puzzle"

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> 1. Mmmhmm, what do we have here? A puzzler looking for a math puzzle. K, it just so happens I have one here! Enjoy. 24 cows live in a barn. 7 of the bricks on the roof of the barn fall off. 3 of those bricks hit the ground. 3 of those bricks pass through the ground. 7 days later, where is the last brick?

Comment: *votes to close too broad* :P

Comment: @micsthepick I bet you were the downvoter, pessimist :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the puzzle actually is

> **Make 24** from **7**, **3**, **3** and **7**

As you get this by taking

> the first characters of each sentence (the bits in bold are what is actually there - I added the rest as filler)

So:

> $(3/7+3) * 7 =24$

Comment: Where's the 'from'?

Comment: @WilliamNathanael there isn't one. The first letters say 'MAKE 24 7 3 3 7' and I just added the rest in. The bits in caps are what actually is written

Comment: 24 is not a letter.

Comment: @Jasen editted to ‘characters’

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe it's a play of words and that 4 bricks went into the ground 'beef' and that 3 of those made it through, leaving 1 inside the ground beef.
So, we find our 7 bricks.

Comment: This was one of those *you either see it or you don't* puzzles. For what it's worth, I was stumped until reading the other answer. Good try!